Using MUI Treeview in Mui Autocomplete
I was wondering if there was any way to have the mui treeview available as the option in the mui autocomplete dropdown. I looked around a lot but could not find any references or examples for it, Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is an image for reference:

Using the treeview directly in the renderOptions does not seem to work.

You can pass in a custom ListboxComponent. Have you tried that?

@super i did, problem comes up in navigating the treeview, each time you select it, the dropdown is closed
